# how to run chmod in python?

Tags: python, chmod

I was working with a sensor called Rplidar. To connect the Rplidar with my operating system(Ubuntu) sometimes i have to use this command in the terminal:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

After running this instruction, ubuntu can detect the Rplidar. Later on, i will run a python script to work with the Rplidar. Now I want to include this command inside my python script so that i do not need to run it in the terminal before working with the Rplidar. Is there any way that i could do it in python script?

Comment: `os.system("sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0")` but I'm not sure what if system ask for password.

Comment: or subprocess.run("sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0")

Comment: `os.system("echo password | sudo -S chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0")` ?

Comment: You should fix the access to the device node instead of running `chmod`. In most cases you just need to put the user in a group (the one that owns the node), log out and in again. If that fail, you should write a udev rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that `chmod` is provided in the `os` module in Python:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod

so all you need to do is run:

```
import os
filename = 'example.dat'
os.chmod(filename,
    stat.S_IRUSR |
    stat.S_IWUSR |
    stat.S_IRGRP |
    stat.S_IWGRP |
    stat.S_IROTH)
```

so there's no need to shell out to perform this operation normally. Also have a look at the `os.path` and `shutil` modules for much more support in this area.

Things get a little complicated if you need to perform this operation with elevated privileges, but that's actually not the solution here.

Also, it is not a good idea to give 666 permissions to system devices. This can open up security problems when any user on the system has read/write access to system devices. As a matter of principle, use the least permissions required for correct operation.

As @KlausD. comments, you shouldn't be forcing permission changes on these device nodes anyway. The correct approach is to perform a one-time operation of adding the relevant user to the `dialout` group on your system. Then by being in the correct group, the user running your application will have access to the device.  This is already answered here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0

Just run this once:

```
sudo adduser kazi dialout
```

then log out and back in for it to take effect. Your Rplidar app will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subprocess` library to run shell command in Python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "chmod", "666", "/dev/ttyUSB0"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: how can i provide the password? @VietHTran

Comment: @Kazi You can try something similar with what @furas suggested above by replacing the `Popen` line above with `subprocess.Popen("echo '<password>' | sudo -S  chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`